# How to get a valid SharePoint web from input URL

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Working with a SharePoint 2010 Visual Studio workflow that will copy data from a local farm to a remote farm using web services.

I'm having trouble trying to parse an input URL to get the corresponding web on the remote farm.

Example inputs:

```
https://test2.remotefarm.com/randomweb/webweb/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx
https://test3.remotefarm.com/
```

I have no control over what the input will be, so it could be the root web app or five webs deep.

Once I have a valid web URL, I will be appending a web service endpoint.

**Edit - This is what I ended up using**

```
Uri fileUrl = new Uri("https://test2.remotefarm.com/randomweb/webweb/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx"); 

        //Websref is a Web Reference pointing to \webs.aspx
        websRef.Webs webs1 = new websRef.Webs();
        webs1.Url = "https://" + fileUrl.Authority + "/" + sWebsSuffix;
        webs1.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        string strWebUrl = webs1.WebUrlFromPageUrl(fileUrl.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SPSite to get the site collection from the URL and then get the Web app using OpenWeb(). For example:

```
using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite("https://test2.remotefarm.com/randomweb/webweb/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx"))
{
SPWeb myWeb = siteCollection.OpenWeb();
//do stuff with myWeb here

}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. The workflow runs on the local farm, using the code you provided would work locally, but not when referencing the remotefarm.

Comment: Apologies, you will need to use SPFarm.Open() first, although this assumes certain conditions to access the remote farm. If you cannot access the farm in this way, then you will need to use SharePoint Web Services. SPFarm.Open reference - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms453293(v=office.14).aspx